# SQL select recursively

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have the following table

```
UserID  | User knows
--------------------
a       |          b
a       |          c
c       |          e
c       |          a
d       |          f
d       |          g
```

I want to get a list in order to know which users are connected (also via each others).

e.g for user (a) the list should contain:  b,c,e,a

Is there a way to do it in sql or do I have to code something?

Comment: Which SQL database are you using? Can you edit the question to state it please

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using? And version? Many have features that allow recursion to occur, but syntaxes can vary between products (and between product versions)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using SQL Server 2005 or newer try something like this:

```
WITH userCTE
AS ( 

    SELECT UserKnows
    FROM users
    WHERE UserId = 'a'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT UserKnows
    FROM users
    INNER JOIN userCTE 
     ON users.UserId= userCTE.UserKnows
    WHERE users.UserId != 'a'
)
SELECT *
FROM userCTE
```

You can see it in action here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/1832/0

Comment: This will also work on PostgreSQL, Firebird (if you add the mandatory recursive keyword), Teradata and Oracle.